# Will renaming my Windows partition from BOOTCAMP break anything?

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I've installed Windows 7 via BootCamp. I'd like to rename the partition from BOOTCAMP to something a little easier on the eyes. Will renaming my Windows partition from "BOOTCAMP" to "Windows" break anything? (Should I do it from the Windows side or the Mac side?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't break anything. Only issue is that if you're using a FAT partition, the name will be all capitals. Rename from either Windows or OS X if you have an appropriate driver installed.

Comment: This answer is not right, You cannot rename NTFS partition from standard Mac OS X install without third party NTFS driver

Comment: You're right, I had NTFS3G installed when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it should not break anything. I would do it while booted into Windows, because I would assume that Windows would know to make sure the change is reflected anywhere else it is necessary.

(I'm not an expert on Windows but I did rename my BOOTCAMP partition under Snow Leopard without any negative results.)